# Cargo deploy uses proxy settings when it shouldn't

Tags: maven, proxy, tomcat7, maven-cargo

I'm using cargo to deploy my project to a test server. The cargo config is fine, works well on my local machine. However, on the hudson machine it always fails with a stacktrace showing:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 407 for URL: http://ppdtest.kbcsecurities.net:8080/manager/text/list
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1313)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:507)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:644)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:657)
at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:173)
... 34 more
```

The thing is however, I have NO proxy defined anywhere. Not in my setting.xml, not in the pom.xml files (parent or childs).
Anyone has some pointers or help to offer?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this is a proxy problem? The URL looks like it's Tomcat's Manager application. Can you verify that you're using the right credentials for your Tomcat instance?

If you want to make sure that no proxy is involved, please check the environment variables of the machine to see whether there's any global proxy setting that Java could be picking up, either in the global Maven options or in the options for Hudson.

One other thing to try is whether you can access the URL in question using a browser from the Hudson machine. If it's a headless machine, you can use a terminal browser like [links](http://www.jikos.cz/~mikulas/links/) and see if you can authenticate with that.